# What's the difference between a module and a subsystem

Tags: jboss, wildfly

In the context of JBoss and Wildfly, what's the difference between a module and a subsystem?

Answer (score 4):

Jboss modules is a class loading system:

> JBoss Modules is a standalone implementation of a modular (non-hierarchical) class loading and execution environment for Java. In other words, rather than a single class loader which loads all JARs into a flat class path, each library becomes a module which only links against the exact modules it depends on, and nothing more. It implements a thread-safe, fast, and highly concurrent delegating class loader model, coupled to an extensible module resolution system, which combine to form a unique, simple and powerful system for application execution and distribution.
>   [Guide for Class Loading in WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)

Subsystems are the groups of customizable features of Jboss:

> The EE subsystem provides common functionality in the Java EE platform, such as the EE Concurrency Utilities (JSR 236) and @Resource injection. The subsystem is also responsible for managing the lifecycle of Java EE application's deployments, that is, .ear files.
>   The EE subsystem configuration may be used to: 
>   customise the deployment of Java EE applications,
>       create EE Concurrency Utilities instances,
>       define the default bindings
>   [Guide for subsystem configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Subsystem+configuration)

Comment: So what's the difference?