# Cannot get the deploy to work because of mysql

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using the Spring MVC login example (available by Eclipse/Spring Tools on creating a new Spring MVC project) to learn more about Spring. By default the example uses the H2 memory database. Though, I am trying to switch from H2 to MySQL. When, I say trying I mean that I have been doing this for the past 7-8 hours.

The login example uses Maven. So, I have added the following code to pom.xml to get mysql:

```
SOMECODEABOVETHIS
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then, I went ahead and modified the *-ds.xml file:

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MyProjectDSBasic"
                pool-name="MyProjectDemo" enabled="true"
                use-java-context="true">

        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDB</connection-url>  
        <driver>mysql</driver>
        <security>  
            <user-name>root</user-name>  
            <password></password>  
        </security>  
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
            <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
            <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

Note that the "drivers" block was an answer that I have picked from another question on syntaxoverflow. Also, I have experimented with and without the" driver-class" block.

This is the modified persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primarybasic">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MyProjectDSBasic</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" 
                      value="java:jboss/MyProject/persistencebasic" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have used both Wildfly 9 and Tomcat 8. They both give me the same error on deployment:

> WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.data-source.java:jboss/datasources/MyProjectDSBasic is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql]"]}

Note that I have cleaned my maven and made sure the mysql connector is on the Maven referenced library. I have no idea how to fix this. I must have read over 200 pages trying to find a solution without luck. I have even read about some module.xml where you put more information about the mysql connector but I do not have that file on the project. If I am to create it, I do not know where I would place it.

I am not using Spring Boot by the way.

Comment: Is the correct version of the MySQL driver accessible on the server? You probably need to have the 5.1.38 version of the jar under the `modules` folder, as explained [here](https://lijianzhao.wordpress.com/2016/07/02/install-mysql-jdbc-driver-on-wildfly/). Another reason could be a name mismatch with `resource-ref` in `web.xml` vs. the `jndi` name of the data source (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23693400/905488)).

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic, thanks a lot for the reply. No resource-ref at the web.xml file. As for the first solution, does not that defeat the whole purpose of automation and deployment?

Comment: Not sure, but I _think_ that dependencies that have to do with data sources are considered infrastructure that needs to be in place before the actual application is deployed. After all, the data source definitions themselves are static.

Comment: I really hope there is a better approach to doing this without having to resort to the manual adding of the jar. I mean after all the MySQL driver works with Hibernate ORM without having to add anything.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have created under Wildfly module com.mysql? If not you have to do it.
Wildfly requires a module for database drivers.

Here is my answer over modules in Wildfly:

[What's the difference between a module and a subsystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922826/whats-the-difference-between-a-module-and-a-subsystem/47932956#47932956][1])

And here https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly?_sscc=t

how are to create a module in Jboss7 or Wildfly